# Функция что-бы вывести фамилию и инициалы

Tags: c, строки, вывод

Ребят, пишу программу, кроме всего прочего в ней надо вывести фамилию и инициалы( в файле откуда программа берёт данные написано полное фио) подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать..

Answer (score 0):

https://ideone.com/pX0VzJ

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char ln[256], fn, mn;
  
  for(unsigned q=0; q<5; ++q)
  {
    scanf("%s ", ln);
    scanf("%c%*[^ \r\n]", &fn);
    scanf(" %c%*[^ \r\n]", &mn);
    
    printf("%s %c. %c.\n", ln, fn, mn);
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```